# cypress mounting vue3 component with defineProps and defineEmits throwing typescript error

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, cypress

When I write a vue3 component with a `defineProps()` and a `defineEmits()`, in cypress testing, when I mount the component with a spy for the emitted function, the typescript compiler throws an error.

In the vue3 component:

```
const prop = defineProps<{
    dive: Dive,
    user: User,
    divers: User[],
    conveners: User[]
}>()

const emit = defineEmits<{
    (e: 'reload'): void
}>()
```

And the cypress test:

```
const onReloadSpy = cy.spy().as('onReloadSpy')
cy.mount(
  DiveComponent,
  {
    props: {
      onReload: onReloadSpy,
      dive: getDefaultDive(),
      user: getUser( "Convener" ),
      conveners: [] as User[],
      divers: [] as Dive[],
    }
  }
)
```

The typescript error is:

```
src/components/__tests__/DiveComponent.spec.ts(202,11): error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'DefineComponent<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<{ dive: Dive; user: User; divers: User[]; conveners: User[]; }>, {}, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 6
more ..., {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptionsWithObjectProps<Readonly<ComponentPropsOptions>, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, string[
], string>'.
      Type 'DefineComponent<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<{ dive: Dive; user: User; divers: User[]; conveners: User[]; }>, {}, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 6 more ...,
{}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentOptionsBase<{ [x: number]: unknown; [x: `on${Capitalize<string>}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; readonly length?: number | Prop<unknown,
unknown> | null | undefined; readonly toString: (() => string) & string; ... 20 more ...; readonly flat?: Prop<...> | ... 2 more ... | undefined; }, ... 11 more...'.
        Types of property 'setup' are incompatible.
          Type '((this: void, props: LooseRequired<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<{ dive: Dive; user: User; divers: User[]; conveners: User[]; }>>> & { ...; }
 & {}>, ctx: { ...; }) => void | ... 2 more ... | Promise<...>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((this: void, props: LooseRequired<{ [x: number]: unknown; [x: `on${Capitalize<string
>}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; readonly length?: number | Prop<unknown, unknown> | null | undefined; readonly toString: (() => string) & string; ... 20 more ...; readonly flat
?: Prop<...> | ... 2 more ... | undefined; ...'.
            Type '(this: void, props: LooseRequired<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<{ dive: Dive; user: User; divers: User[]; conveners: User[]; }>>> & { ...;
} & {}>, ctx: { ...; }) => void | ... 2 more ... | Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(this: void, props: LooseRequired<{ [x: number]: unknown; [x: `on${Capitalize<string>}`]: ((...ar
gs: any[]) => any) | undefined; readonly length?: number | Prop<unknown, unknown> | null | undefined; readonly toString: (() => string) & string; ... 20 more ...; readonly flat?: Prop<...>
| ... 2 more ... | undefined; }...'.
              Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
                Type 'LooseRequired<{ [x: number]: unknown; [x: `on${Capitalize<string>}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; readonly length?: number | Prop<unknown, unknown> |
null | undefined; readonly toString: (() => string) & string; ... 20 more ...; readonly flat?: Prop<...> | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & {}>' is missing the following properties from type
 'LooseRequired<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<{ dive: Dive; user: User; divers: User[]; conveners: User[]; }>>> & { ...; } & {}>': conveners, dive, user, divers, onReload
```

As best I can tell, typescript insists that `onReload` is not a property that can be defined on `DiveComponent`. However, I haven't been able to find any other mechanism of passing an `onReload` spy to the component.

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue?